# New GFCI outlet not working

Tags: gfci

We just moved into a 2001 home. All the switches and outlets are that nasty beige color, so I am replacing them all with white switches, outlets and covers. Problem in the kitchen GFCI: I wired in a new GFCI outlet the same as the old one, and it won't reset. Totally dead. I reinstalled the old one and it works fine.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you certain that you wired the incoming power wires to the new GFCI's "LINE" terminals and not the "LOAD" ones? Check that the old & new GFCIs are labeled with their LINE & LOAD in the same positions.

Comment: The newer GFCIs will also require an initial reset after initially having power applied to the LINE terminals.

Comment: Definitely check that the LOAD and LINE terminals match between the new and old outlets. Had a new and old set of GFCI outlets, both made by Leviton, and the LOAD & LINE positions had been swapped, so check!

Answer (score 1):

GFCI receptacles can go bad, and even new ones can be defective.  Try another one.  (And, of course, triple check that you are wiring to the LINE terminals.  And confirm that the one you are replacing will successfully Test and Reset so you know you have a clean load.)